# Why a character can be stored in and printed from a int type variable and double type variable but not from a float type variable?

Tags: types, floating-point, int, double

Code-1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    scanf("%c", &i);
    printf("%c", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Code-2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double i;
    scanf("%c", &i);
    printf("%c", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Code-3:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float i;
    scanf("%c", &i);
    printf("%c", i);
    return 0;
}
```

In case of Code-1 & Code-2, if i give 'A' or any character as input, the character is printed as output.
But in case of Code-3, if i give 'A' or any character as input, no output is given.

What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Please provide the code as text and not as images, please.

Comment: Done @Michael Czechowski

Comment: When you add a further tag with the programming language, you will get better code highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double i;
    scanf("%c", &i);
    printf("%c", i);
    return 0;
}
```

you are using `scanf` and `printf` incorrectly. With the `%c` specifier in `scanf`, you are **required** (in order to conform to standard C) to pass a pointer to `char`. With the `%c` specifier in `printf`, you are **required** to pass an `int` value. When you break the rules, your program breaks, and broken things malfunction.

What likely happens in your specific case is that, during the `scanf`, the character read is, by happenstance, left in a processor register. That may be the processor register that happens to be also used for passing an integer argument in the second position of a function call. Let’s call it S. When, you you call `printf`, the compiler puts the value of `i` into the register used for passing floating-point arguments. Let’s call that F. This leaves the other processor registers unchanged. Then, when `printf` executes and sees the `%c`, it gets the value from S. This still has the value from `scanf`, so it is printed.

When you do this with `float`, then, for some unknown reason, the value in S is not left unchanged. Between the `scanf` and the `printf`, the compiler may have used S for something else. One difference is that, when you use a `float` value as an argument, the compiler has to convert it to a `double` value (per a rule of C). In doing that conversion, it might have used S for an address or something.

In the case with `int`, what may have happened is that the memory allocated for `i` had not been used previously in the process, so it contained zeros because the operating system clears memory before giving it to a process. The `scanf` then put one byte into `i`. Your system is little endian, meaning that the lowest addressed byte of an object is the lest significant byte of the value, so setting the byte to the character read resulted in `i` having the value of the byte.

Comment: But what about Code-1?